# What is ApplicationEvents.vb file from

Tags: vb.net

Just noticed a file named ApplicationEvents.vb in my vb.net project in the solution explorer, its empty...

Where would this have come from? is it safe to delete?

Comment: Why should this question be closed as *primarily opinion-based*?

Comment: It came from clicking Project + Properties, Application tab, View Application Events button.  Deleting it again is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a file that can house common `Application` events like `Startup` and `Shutdown`. This is a partial class, so it would get compiled in when building the solution.

If it is empty, then it is safe to delete, but if you ever want to handle these events, then this is where you can easily hook into these events.

Read [How to: Handle Application Events (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2bys999%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Im using visual studio 10

The applicationevents.vb is not safe to delete if its empty.   The project will fail to build properly because the file is missing.  The project has some kind of internal reference to the file if you have created it.   By default this file is not included unless you have clicked the "Application Events" button on the application tab in the project properties....

what I really want to know is why is mine blank....

Comment: I am using VS2017 Community and VisualSVN. ApplicationEvents.vb appeared when I set the assembly level. I removed it by "Revert Changes..." VisualSVN and the project built fine.